# Manually date chages issue in android

Tags: android

I am developing app in android.The app has feature of manually uploading of data.The issue related to time i.e. if user changes date from setting of tab,suppose he sets the date of tomorrow.As data inserted for that particular date.That wrong data(date) get uploaded .Instead of today's date.

Answer (score 1):

Your server should be using its own date, ignoring the date set by the client, if this concerns you. The date can be changed on most client devices, such as Windows machines, OS X machines, Linux machines, Android devices, ...

Comment: @sam08: If you don't have a server, then I have no idea where the "manual uploading of data" is going to, and there is little you can do about the user's choice of time.

Comment: Thanks for reply.... I have application in which data is stored locally in sqlite database.When user select upload data option manually at that time the data gets uploaded to server.But Before uploading of data user might change the data and wrong date value may get stored to database.So Wrong date uploaded to server.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this problem by sending location information instead on date and time ,the server can identify the location and can get the current time but this can vary according to your requirements.